# Maximum fraction of students who get 50% or below, when the average for an exam is 85% and maximum score is 100%?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am simply using Markov's Inequality here in the manner:

For X to be the number of points earned, where E[X] = 85

P(X $\leq50$) = 1 - P(X>50)

To calculate P(X>50) I have :

P(X>50) $\leq$ $\frac{E[X]}{50}$ = $\frac{85}{50}$, which should give us P(X $\leq50$) as 1 - $\frac{85}{50}$, which is obviously wrong.

What am I missing here. I believe it has to do with the maximum score, but I am not sure how it afffects the Markov's Inequality.

Comment: This is an algebra problem.  You want all the ones above $50$ to get $100$ and all the low ones to get exactly $50$.  Calculate the fraction getting $50$ that will make the average $85$

Comment: Yes I do understand that which will give us an answer of $\frac{3}{10}$, but how can we solve this using Markov's Inequality. On using a random variable Y = 100-X, we get the desired answer but I don't understand why random variable X doesn't work.

Comment: @10Minhelp does my answer clear it up for you? Specifically, Markov's inequality is an _inequality_. It won't _always_ give you the bound that you want. It's a skill, almost an art, to be able to prove stuff using it!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an *inequality* which need not be tight. You correctly applied Markov's inequality to find
$$ P(X > 50) \le E(X) / 50 = 85/50. $$
But the RHS is larger than $1$! This is useless: all probabilities are trivially at most $1$. Still, it's not *false*. It's just not *useful*. So you get
$$ P(X \le 50) \ge 1 - 85/50 = - 35/50. $$
Again, not *false*, just not *useful*. Importantly, the first relation is an *inequality*, not an equality.

Markov's inequality is a wonderful tool and I use it all the time. It often gives very useful results, albeit sometimes with some slight massaging to get in the most useful form. But that doesn't mean that *every* application will give useful results.

Further, it's definitely an *inequality*. Look  up the proof---or, better, prove if yourself---and you'll see that it's very rarely tight. Basically never. Thus you should never think of the $\le$ as $\approx$, unless you have good external reasons to do so and a good quantification of $\approx$.